# How to make a PHP login with DreamWeaver?

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm a real beginner with php and html as well. I'm trying to make a very simple login for the html page of the Institute I work for. There is actually no user and just one password.

Since the information isn't crucial, I don't need a high security level. The whole project uses DreamWeaver 8. I'm not a good programmer and not a web programmer at all so this code is very simple and possibly not a good approach.

In the html code there is just a form:

```
<form action="method.php" method="post">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

(I have this in some template which works fine)
the method is in a different file and looks like this

```
<?php
$password = $_POST["password"]
if($password == Pass){
        header ("Location: unterlagen.html")
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong password"
    }
```

?>

(This is the whole php file)
If I enter the password or just hit enter or login firefox asks me weather I want to save or open the method.php.
I think I changed something. Before an empty page just opened.
If my approach is bad, I'm very much open to suggestions. I just need some simple login and I would like to not have the method which checks the password in my html code.

Comment: You should really follow some tutorials on the basics before trying these things.  I don't even think you have a webserver running. It's trying to download your PHP file because you have no interpreter. Or you don't have your project setup in the correct folder.  http://www.howtogeek.com/177129/beginner-geek-how-to-host-your-own-website-on-windows-wamp/

Comment: Also, this line should be if($password == "Pass"){

Comment: I tried w3schools but havn't done much there. Do you have any other recommondation?

Comment: I don't think I have a webserver running. I just have the files for tests. I try your link(WampServer) for making a Webserver. This method.php should just be executed when a password is submitted. I think really need to do more tutorials. Thank you for your comments so far!

Comment: See my profile if you want to see how login is done. Whilst that is more complicated than you need, the practice of following through the material will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed out the semi-colon.

```
<?php
$password = $_POST["password"];
$Pass = ''; // whatever your password is
if($password == $Pass){
    header ("Location: unterlagen.html");
} else {
    echo "wrong password";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so far that was actually helpful. I'm still struggling with one issue: When I press login or return to submit the password, firefox asks how to open or download method.php which is not my goal. I just want to open the unterlagen.html page or show the error message as decribed in the code. I want to execute the php-file not open it. I propably get this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) doesn't work on navigator or client side. You need a server with PHP support like [apache](http://www.apache.org/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/) or [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) before being able to debug your code. You run the server after having stored your code on it, then you use your navigator to get to it. PHP will be rendered in the server side, you'll only get the final rendered outputs.

Try to start with a ready to use PHP development environment like [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on your local machine. Or try to upload your files (*at least `method.php` file*) to some working server with php support.

Here is a good [video tutorials series to start with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUV3iv9xOs&list=PL442FA2C127377F07).